# Quarkus Apache Camel AWS Lambda CDI ProducerTemplate result NullPointerException

Tags: java, aws-lambda, apache-camel, quarkus

I'm try reproduce the follow code  [Deploying a Camel Route in AWS Lambda : A Camel Quarkus example](https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus-examples/tree/camel-quarkus-main/aws-lambda) in my own code [Quarkus Camel AWS Lambda](https://github.com/DouglasGo8/mmp-aws-certification-dev-assoc/tree/master/mp-lambda-quarkus), but the ProducerTemplate returns NullPointerExcetion, as can see in this link [BUG_CAMEL_QUARKUS_LAMBDA](https://github.com/DouglasGo8/mmp-aws-certification-dev-assoc/blob/master/content/pic/CDI_CAMEL_INJECT_BUG.png)

```
    @Named("languageScoreLambda")
public class LanguageScoreLambda implements RequestHandler<Language, LanguageScoreDto> {

  @Inject
  ProducerTemplate template;

  @Override
  public LanguageScoreDto handleRequest(Language input, Context context) {
    System.out.println("#Template isNull ===> " + (null == template)); // true
    return new LanguageScoreDto("5", input.getLanguage());
  }
}
```

Comment: The screenshot doesn't show a nullpointerexception. It just shows that template is null.

Comment: Correct, because it's just a sample, this is the result of the AWS Lambda component screen

Answer (score 0):

I Found the issue, as I've been using Terraform to provide the AWS Lambda function the handler **MUST BE** *io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler::handleRequest*
bellow the raw code snippted

```
  resource "aws_lambda_function" "hello_lambda" {
  function_name    = var.AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME
  filename         = "${path.module}/function.zip"
  role             = aws_iam_role.hello_lambda_role.arn
  depends_on       = [aws_cloudwatch_log_group.hello_lambda_logging]
  runtime          = "java11"
  handler          = io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler::handleRequest
  timeout          = 10
  memory_size      = 256
}
```